# Simple TCP client?

Tags: android, tcpclient, esp8266

I'm trying to program a simple android TCP client app to send data to a esp8266 server. I have tested the esp server with roboremo and it works. I followed a yt tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=29y4X65ZUwE&t=350s), i had to change some syntax errors, i used the android studio recommendations. I am monitoring what the esp receives with simulink (visa loopback). Roboremo works fine, my app doesn't send anything. I checked the IP and port multiple times.

MainActivity class code:

```
package com.example.tinemasilo.tcptest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText e1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);


}

public void send(View v)
{
    MessegeSender messegeSender = new MessegeSender();
    messegeSender.execute(e1.getText().toString());
}
}
```

MessegeSender class code:

```
package com.example.tinemasilo.tcptest;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MessegeSender extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>
{
    Socket s;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    PrintWriter pw;
    private String messege;
    private String[] voids;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... voids)
    {
        this.voids = voids;
        String[] messege = this.voids;

        try
        {
            s = new Socket("192.168.4.1",502);
            pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            pw.write(String.valueOf(messege));
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there errors in the logcat output? Where do you call your send function?

Comment: `pw.write(String.valueOf(messege));`. That should be `pw.write(voids[0]);`

Comment: There are no errors in logcat. I tried `pw.write(voids[0]);` but it still doesn't work.